# listagg: remove adjacent duplicates

Tags: duplicates, group-concat, listagg, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have timestamped data and want to create a list from one column, with *adjacent duplicates* (but not all duplicates) collapsed into one.

For example, given the following data:

```
'2001-01-01 00:00:01' 'a'
'2001-01-01 00:00:02' 'a'
'2001-01-01 00:00:03' 'b'
'2001-01-01 00:00:04' 'b'
'2001-01-01 00:00:05' 'b'
'2001-01-01 00:00:06' 'a'
'2001-01-01 00:00:07' 'a'
'2001-01-01 00:00:08' 'c'
'2001-01-01 00:00:09' 'a'
```

— I would want the result to be `'a','b','a','c','a'`.

I am using Snowflake, which has `listagg(distinct foo)` and `listagg(distinct foo) within group(order by bar)` and even `listagg(distinct foo) within group(order by bar) over(partition by baz)`, but I don't see a way to do what I need (nor is Google helping). I would really, really like to avoid a `join`.

If you know a solution in another dialect that has `listagg` or `group_concat`, please post it, and I'll attempt to translate it to Snowflake for my use. Many thanks.

---

Things that don't work:

- I tried `trim(regexp_replace('~' || listagg(foo, '~') || '~', '~([^~]+~)\\1', '~\\1'), '~')`, but Snowflake doesn't allow `\1` in the match pattern: I get the error `Invalid regular expression: '~([^~]+~)\1', invalid escape sequence: \1`.
- I tried `listagg(iff(lag(foo) ignore nulls over(partition by baz order by bar)=foo, null, foo), ',') within group(order by bar) over(partition by baz)` but got the error `Window function [LAG(...)] may not be nested inside another window function.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Snowflake supports backreferences in regexp patterns, unfortunately.

Possible solutions:

- eliminate duplicates in an input stream using LAG, e.g.

  ```
  with sub as (select foo, bar, lag(bar) over (order by foo) barlag)
  select listagg(foo) within group order by (bar) from foo 
  where barlag is null or barlag <> lag;
  ```
- use LISTAGG, but write a JavaScript UDF that splits a result of LISTAGG and eliminate duplicates there
- write a JavaScript UDTF (table function) that performs LISTAGG with duplicate elimination